# Troubles with heap sorting algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

I am working on a school assignment that involves making changes to an unfinished heap API to work with a pre-written program (written by my professor).

I have done a lot of searching on the different ways to sort a heap and cannot get the proper output for the program. I will try to break down what is going on in depth.

The heap stores a basic struct called "Node" that holds void *data.

1. An empty heap is created
2. One at a time, 15 integers are passed into an insertNode() function. This function creates a Node from the int and gets added to the next available spot in the heap (doesnt do any sorting). That function is below.

   ```
   void insertNode(Heap *heap, void *data){
       /* Create node from the int */    
       Node *new = createNode(data);
       size_t newIndex = 0;

       if(heap->currentSize + 1 > heap->maxSize){
           printf("Heap is full. No more Nodes can be added.\n");
           return;
       } else {
           /* heap->currentSize is the number of Nodes that are in the heap */
           newIndex = heap->currentSize;
       }

       heap->heapArray[newIndex] = new;
       heap->currentSize = heap->currentSize + 1;

       heapify(heap, newIndex);
   }
   ```
3. At the end of insertNode(), the heapify() function is called. This is the function that I believe is causing the problem. I'm still very confused on the correct algorithm to use for this recursive sort. Here is the heapify function below.

   ```
   void heapify(Heap *heap, size_t i){

       /* Gets the index of the parent of the node at index i */
       /* NOTE: this function was provided and is correct */
       size_t p = getParentIndex(i);
       if(p == -1){
           /* New Node is at index 0 (no sort needed) */
           return;
       }

       /* uses a function pointer to a compare function in the heap struct 
       NOTE: (min heap) */
       if(heap->compare(heap->heapArray[i], heap->heapArray[p]) < 0){
           swap(heap->heapArray[p], heap->heapArray[i];

           /* Recursively call heapify with the parents index */
           heapify(heap, p);
       }

   }
   ```

**OUTPUTS**

The numbers are inserted into the heap in the order:

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4
```

And the expected output when the heapArray is printed in order is:

```
4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
```

MY incorrect output is as follows:

```
4, 8, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 13, 10, 7, 9, 18, 16, 6, 19
```

Here is the Expected Output visualized as a tree:
[Sorry about my MS Paint skillz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xByFT.png)

Here is my Output visualized as a tree:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oesN1.png)

I hope this is enough information to identify the problem. Feel free to ask about anything ive missed.

EDIT: My output visualized as a tree is from a previous attempt at solving the problem. An accident on my part. My current output is the array written out. The visualization can serve as another attempt that didnt work.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @MHRasel's explanation I solved my problem. All it took was adding these 7 lines of code to the end of my insertNode() function.

```
for(int i = heap->currentSize - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    swap(heap->heapArray[0], heap->heapArray[i];
    heap->currentSize = heap->currentSize - 1;

    heapify(heap, i);
}
```

Comment: The algorithm you provided is a heap algorithm, now you need to write the heap sort algorithm. In that algorithm, you will iteratimely swap the root with the last element of the heap, reduce the heap size and run the heapfy method. That is how it work. Please refer to any heap sort algorithm to get better idea.

Comment: What led you to conclude that the children of 4 are 6 and 19?

Comment: @rici Im not sure, that is what my current program is outputting. Not what it is supposed to be outputting.

Comment: @evs21: According to the output you provide, the children of 4 are 8 and 14, but you drew them as 6 and 19. Why?

Comment: @rici I think I made the visual with an output from a previous attempt without noticing. Thanks for pointing out... thats what i get for having messy notes

Comment: Seems to me like the error is probably somewhere else. Hard to know without seeing a [mcve]

Comment: @MHRasel Thank you! I fixed it and added my solution in the original question as an edit.

Comment: Don't be surprised when you don't get good marks on your assignment. That "solution," while it appears to work, is not a good general solution to your problem. It's seriously non-optimum, and shouldn't even be necessary if your `insertNode` function is working correctly. We can't really diagnose your problem, though, because you haven't shown us all the relevant code. I strongly suggest that you re-read and *study* the information about how binary heaps work, because it's obvious that you don't have a clear understanding.